# Disable / characters keycode 111 with java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying disable / character but my code not working!

```
$('#link').keypress(function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 111){
            return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: First, are you getting the right `keyCode`? I get `47` when I hit `/`. What do you really mean you're trying to "disable" it? Saying it's "not working" isn't very helpful.

Comment: That is it! I put wrong keyCode. Thanks! :)

Comment: FYI - from jQuery: `It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input.`

Answer (score 0):

replace `return false` with `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#link').keypress(function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 111){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that some browsers use `keyCode`, and the others use `which`.
So:

If you're using JQuery, you should use `event.which` ([more detail](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)):

```
$('#link').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 111){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

If not, you can use like this:

```
$('#link').keypress(function (e) {
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode || 0;
  if (key == 111){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```